# Can PageSpeed Insights show a breakdown by device or browser for visitors that score 'poor' for FCP, LCP, and CLS?

Tags: google-search-console, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I'm looking to better understand the population of site visitors to our site that fall in the 'poor'/red zone of FCP, LCP, and CLS of our Field Data metrics on PageSpeed Insights.

Does anyone know of a way to analyze these populations? Questions I'm trying to answer: are these visitors using a specific device/browser type? Or is there some other way we can understand who these people are that experience sub-par site performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Questions I'm trying to answer: are these visitors using a specific
> device/browser type?

Note that Google's field data is coming from Chrome (and then only users whose privacy settings allow for it), so for what is shown in PSI, CrUX etc. there is no question of what browser was used. This is an important point because it is likely not a representative sample of your users.

That aside, you can get *some* greater depth of analysis from [CrUX](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/) via [BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/home). There's an [SQL query cookbook](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/CrUX/tree/main/sql) to get you started. Probably not quite the depth you are looking for, though.

For that, I think you'll need to deploy the [Web Vitals JS library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) to collect your own data.

Comment: I use the web vitals library and create reports that combine the core web vitals data with other analytics data like browser and region. You get a lot more detail and it works on multiple browsers.